# Не отображается вкладка Отзывы в товаре

Tags: woocommerce

У меня в товаре не отображается вкладка отзывы, только описание. В настройках товаров Woocommerce отзывы включены и в карточке товаров тоже. Где ошибка и как её можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Под "Описание" стрелки влево или вправо если подвигать, есть что-то?
Еще в настройках темы могут отключаться отзывы и в куче других плагинов. Попробуйте отключить все плагины, оставив только сам woocommerce. И проверьте настройки темы wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Если стрелку "Описание" двигать - ничего не происходит, двигается только слово описание. Все плагины отключила, кроме Woodcommerce - всё точно так же. Есть только поле "Комментарии" в конце страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]